# How to display the last page when user clicks on add new row,so that user can view the newly added row using react js and prime react

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I am facing problem to display last page when user clicks on add new row..If we can display the last page,user can view the newly added row directly..i am using prime react with react js

Comment: Hi Meera, welcome. You need to add an example of the code you're using before we can begin to help

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use `useRef` hook in order to reference DataTable component and then manually change its state on adding the row

```
const dataTable = useRef(null);
```

then reference it at your component

```
<DataTable value={results} paginator rows={5} ref={dataTable}>
```

and finally implement your custom method by adding at the end this

```
  const goToLastPage = () => {
    dataTable.current.setState({
      first:
        Math.ceil(results.length / dataTable.current.state.rows) *
        dataTable.current.state.rows - dataTable.current.state.rows
    });
  };
```

Check [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-einstein-ztes5)